# Does linear independence necessitate a nowhere zero flow?

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles

Even a yes or no would do.
$\alpha^i,\beta^i\in\Omega^1M$ for $i=1,...,s$.

I was looking at a linear independent set ${\alpha^1(x),...,\alpha^s(x)}$ for all $x\in M$ and wedge product $\sum_i \alpha^i\land\beta^i=0$.

I'm thinking that since the wedge product is zero then $\beta$ would be the inverse mapping of $\alpha$.  But linear independence necessitates (in one case) all non-zero (vectors).  If $\beta^i=\sum_ja_j^i\alpha^j$ and $a^i_j:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $a^i_j=a^j_i$, would there be an everywhere non-zero flow if $a$ was a homotopy?

Comment: I can't understand what you're talking about here. Some things that need to be clarified: (1) Do you want the $\beta^i$'s to satisfy anything other than the wedge product condition? If not, then just take all the $\beta^i$'s to be zero, and they're irrelevant to the problem. (2) What do you mean by the "inverse mapping" of a differential form? (3) What do differential forms have to do with flows? (4) You've defined $a = (a^i_j)$ as a matrix-valued function. What would it mean for such a thing to be a "homotopy"?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lee for your attention.  In essence, I just added the problem to give a background for why I asked the question in the title.  I am missing a flow symbol like $\Phi$.  My differential manifolds book talks about flow of a vector field which can be applied to a vector field on a manifold.  By "inverse mapping" I'm really just saying there can be a homeomorphism.  True that $\beta^i$ could just be zero.

Comment: I still don't understand the question in the title. Linear independence of what? What does it mean for a flow to be "nowhere zero"??

Comment: My understanding of NZ flow is that there are no vectors which have are defined as zero, meaning all must have magnitude and direction either $>0$ or $<0$.  Thus, if a flow describes a collection of vectors, would their linear independence necessitate a NZ flow?